# RemoteDisconnected (Remote end closed connection without response) while connecting to Docker over SSH

Tags: python, docker, ssh

my Code runs on my local network(using VBOX) but when im trying to run it on another network im getting this Error:

```
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

my code is:

```
import docker
client = docker.DockerClient(base_url ='ssh://george@192.168.56.103')
print(client.images.list())
```

the whole Error message is:

```
C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/George/PycharmProjects/docker_project/docker_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1332, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 272, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 531, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1332, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 272, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\docker\api\daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\docker\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 237, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/George/PycharmProjects/docker_project/docker_test.py", line 25, in <module>
    client = docker.DockerClient(base_url ='ssh://george@192.168.56.103')
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\docker\client.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.api = APIClient(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "C:\Users\George\PycharmProjects\docker_project\venv\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

what could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was not with the connection itself. i tried to run the script localy on the remote server:

```
client = docker.from_env()
```

i had a permission denied exception.
the user must have sudo permission for the docker on the remote server to be able to use the Docker SDK. here more infos how to do that:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/
whenever it made the script works fine.